# php get variable value from other class file function in a different file

Tags: php, class

I have a class like this

```
class myClass{
    public function getContent() {
        $products  = 'something';
    }
}
```

Now there is another file called file.php. In that I have included the class file ike this

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/class.php');
```

Now inside file.php I have made my code like this

```
$test  = new myClass();
$test->$products;
```

But it is not getting the variable. So can someone tell me how to get the variable from another class file function? Any help and suggestions will be really appreaciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function to set the variable.

```
$test  = new myClass();
$test->getContent();
echo $test->products;
```

Anyway, this is confusing, since getContent does not get anything. So, do this.

```
//Rename it to set not get
public function setContent() {
    $this->products  = 'something';
}

$test  = new myClass();
//set it
$test->setContent();
echo $test->products;
```

If you want to get it, then:

```
public function getContent() {
    return $this->products;
}
```

So your complete class, and how to set and get could be like this (I renamed the getter and setter)

```
class myClass {

    private $products;

    public function getProducts() {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function setProducts() {
        $this->products = 'something';
    }

}

$test = new myClass;
$test->setProducts();
echo $test->getProducts();
```

Comment: `echo $test->$products;` should be deleted/replaced ?!

Comment: Why should it be replaced? That is for demonstartion

Comment: It makes the answer confused. And I guess that the `$`is a mistake from the OP.

Comment: $test->$products is completely different from $test->products. The latter is property access by key name, the former is property access by variable string value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things going wrong here.

First up: in order to have a function call return a value, it needs to actually have a `return` statement in it. So your `getContent` does not currently return anything.

Then, in order to store something in a class, you need to make a class property for it. Otherwise the variable will be discarded as the function ends; not what you want.

And lastly; to directly access a variable in a class, you need to use the name directly, without a $ in front. Otherwise you are accessing the property by the name of string value of the used variable, which is something completely different.

Here's some fixed code:

```
class myClass{
    public $products = '';

    public function setContent($content) {
        $this->products  = $content;
    }

    public function getContent() {
      return $this->products;
    }
}


$test  = new myClass();
$test->products; // works
$test->getContents(); // also works
```

You probably need to do some reading up on PHP syntax, because you seem to have some trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class myClass{
    public function getContent() {
        $products  = 'something';
        return $products;
    }
}

$test  = new myClass();
echo $test->getContent();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. It's always better to explain *how and why* as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run the function first. use the code below

```
$p = new myClass;
$p->getContent();
$p->products;
```

Just specify product property

```
class myClass{
    public function getContent() {
        $products  = 'something';
$this->products = $products;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a global variable for myClass:

```
class myClass{
    public $products = '';
    public function getContent() {
        $this->products  = 'something';

    }
}
```

In file.php:

```
$test  = new myClass();
$test->getContent();
echo $test->products; // Print something
```

If you want to get all variables, you can use get_defined_vars() function:

```
class myClass{
    public $vars;
    public function getContent() {
        $products  = 'something';
        $this->vars = (object) get_defined_vars();

    }
}
```

In file.php:

```
$test  = new myClass();
$test->getContent();
echo $test->vars->products; // Print something
```

Comment: Still needs a $ in front of products inside the class property definition.

Answer (score -5):

It wont, because the way you declared `$products` variable has made it local to the `function getContent()`. SO

either you can access the function `$test->getContent()` and `return $products` from in there,

or you can declare `$products` as a `global` member variable to the class as

```
class myClass{
$products;
    public function getContent() {
        $products  = 'something';
    }
}
```

Then you can access as

```
$test  = new myClass();
$test->products;
```

** Code not tested though

Comment: The function still won't work as written, as it's still a local variable there.